# Nagios check_nt plugin is not showing status properly

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, nagios

I have installed nagios3 on ubuntu server with NSClient installed on windows servers. The nagios server is getting the information from windows server properly but the status of server is showing Critical for each drive though there is more space in the windows server.
[image]
The below is parameters which I have entered in the windows.cfg.

```
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               winserver
        service_description     C:\ Drive Space
        check_command           check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l c -w 20 -c 5
        }

define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               winserver
        service_description     D:\ Drive Space
        check_command           check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l d -w 20 -c 10
        }

define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               winserver
        service_description     F:\ Drive Space
        check_command           check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l f -w 15 -c 10
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checks don't report the percentage of space *remaining*, but the percentage of space *used*.  A close look at the screen shot above shows what is returned by the checks.

Most Nagios checks return critical or warning results when something goes *over* a figure rather than *under*.  It is a bit confusing.

So you need to change your critical and warning levels to 80 and 95 or 90.

E.g.

```
define service{
   use generic-service
   host_name winserver
   service_description C:\ Drive Space
   check_command check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l c -w 80 -c 95
}
```

Comment: If you are just getting started with Nagios, I would recommend the book Nagios 3 Enterprise Network Monitoring by Schubert et al.  Great resource!